# How can I apply a global scroll event to multiple React components?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, global

I'm building a React app and I'd like to have a global CSS class that is used to fade in components when they appear in the viewport.

**jQuery**

With jQuery, I might do something like this:

```
const windowHeight = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
const windowWidth = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);

isInViewport(el) {
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  const vertInView = (rect.top <= windowHeight) && ((rect.top + rect.height) >= 0);
  const horInView = (rect.left <= windowWidth) && ((rect.left + rect.width) >= 0);
  return (vertInView && horInView);
};

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  $('.animate').each(function() {
    if(isInViewport($(this)[0])) {
      $(this).addClass('animate--active');
    }
  });
});
```

On scroll, I'd check each element with the `animate` class and if *that* element is in the viewport, add the `animate--active` class to it, which will fade it in.

**React**

In React, I've moved my `isInViewport()` function to a global `Helpers.js` file so any component can make use of it, but I've had to add the scroll event and the dynamic class to *every* component, which makes for a lot of duplicated code. For example:

```
import { isInViewport } from './Helpers.js';

function MyComponent(props) {
  const [inViewport, setInViewport] = useState(false);

  const myComponentRef = useRef();

  function handleScroll(e) {
    setInViewport(isInViewport(myComponentRef.current));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    // unmount
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  const classes = (inViewport) ? 'animate animate--active' : 'animate';

  return (
    <section className={classes} ref={myComponentRef}>
    </section>
  );
}
```

As far as I can tell, this would be the React way of doing this, and this *does* work, but again, it means that every component would require its own state variable, scroll event and class declaration, which adds up to a lot of repetition. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Hooks, Custom Hooks, Custom Hooks

```
import { isInViewport } from './Helpers.js';


function useIsInViewPort(ref) {
 const [inViewport, setInViewport] = React.useState(false);

  function handleScroll(e) {
    setInViewport(isInViewport(ref.current));
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    // unmount
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return inViewport;
}


function Acmp(props) {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  const inViewport = useIsInViewPort(ref); 
  const classes = (inViewport) ? 'animate animate--active' : 'animate';

  return (
    <section className={classes} ref={ref}>
    </section>
  );
}


function Bcmp(props) {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  const inViewport = useIsInViewPort(ref); 

  return (
    <section className={classes} ref={ref}>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: I would use IntersectionObserve (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to avoid the Jquery dependency

Comment: Wouldn't I need to pass the custom hook a particular ref? Also, where should custom hooks live? In the top level App component?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer, I personally create them their own folder, but I guess that depends on your custom hook being reusable.

Comment: I've got a custom hook working now. It takes a ref as an argument and returns the `inViewport` boolean. If you update your answer to do the same, I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks for the tip! It's about time I created a custom hook.

Comment: Looks good, thanks! I updated the hook to return both the `inViewport` boolean AND the animate classes using a `animateClasses` variable. This way I don't need to set them in each component. Don't feel like you need to edit your answer but if anyone sees this, they may want to do the same. Thanks again for your help!